# Determining which disjunct in an xsl:template match matched

Tags: xslt, match

Suppose I have XML like this:

```
<xsl:template match="assessment | section ">
             .
             .
             .
</xsl:template>
```

I do this because I mostly want to treat `assessment` and `section` nodes the same.  However, I do want to treat them a little differently.  How can I tell whether a match was for `assessment` or for `section`?

Comment: I can see that you are answering your own questions. There is nothing wrong with that provided to serve the community. But many of them are very simple, more characteristic of any XSLT tutorial. For example, the last you've just done is poorly formulated. What is the meaning of *treat assessment and section nodes the same* but *treat them a little differently*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="name()='section'">
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may test for**:

```
self::assessment
```

which is slightly more efficient than using the `name()` function.

**However in cases like this I will put the common code in another template** (either named or in a named mode) and will instantiate the common processing like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="common"/>
```